# What should be the maximum gas of a solidity function?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, gas

I've seen that currently max gas per block is 8 million, but what should be the maximum that one solidity function spends to make sure that it is included without delay in a block

Also, to prevent excessive gas, should for each loops be avoided?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

block size is 15 million currently, you would need to offer some good price for your transaction to fit the entire block. for example like 50 gwei multiplied by 15,000,000 by price of ether = 15,000,000 * 0.000000050 * $2100  =  $1575 USD - your price for this transaction.